# ethereum wallet always loads "private net"

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have been running test with a private net. Now, no matter what I do (including removal of test dir), when I launch the wallet, it always open in Private Net mode.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by a mistake in initial setup of the test network and genesis file. The wrong step 'added' an initial data file/log to the main chaindata folder. Once removed, the wallet started working again in the correct mode.